# how to remove the leading space in a text file in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a text file (*.txt) in which I have certain lines starting with a space, I want to remove all the leading spaces. 
The text has almost 20k lines, out of which certain random lines are having a space at the start. Because of which I having difficulty in reading these lines.
I want to remove the leading spaces so that it can be read properly.

Comment: [strtrim](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html) may be useful

Comment: It's not helping.
I am having a text file that looks like
  123  abc   3
  121  ert    4

9875 eyt     4
685   ytrr    5

there is issue in reading the first 2 lines that has leading space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following code:

```
inputFileID=fopen('input.txt','r'); % Open input file for reading
outputFileID=fopen('output.txt','w'); % Open output file for writing

formatted_lines_in_cell_array = textscan(inputFileID,'%s','Delimiter','\n'); % Scan input file, and split to rows
formatted_lines=formatted_lines_in_cell_array {1,1}; % Extract the formatted lines array from the 1x1 cell array output of textscan

fprintf(outputFileID,'%s\r\n',formmated_lines{:}); % Write formatted lines to output file

fclose(inputFileID); % Close files
fclose(outputFileID);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help friend. 
In fact, I got an error :

Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Error in testing (line 4)
    input_line_str=char(A{i}); % Convert current line to str

Comment: Did you import the data from file using `importdata` function, like i did?

Comment: yes, I imported the data. The only change I made to your code was to change the text file name.

Comment: My text file has lines containing texts and a mix of numbers and texts.
Like:
Text file line 1
Text file line 2
 987  axs  4
 347  vgr  2
1999  vht  2

Comment: I edited my answer with a simpler solution, check if that works for you

Comment: what does the line, "formmated_lines=formmated_lines{1,1};" mean. Sorry my questions are very basic

Comment: If you look at the output of the previous line, you will see it returns a variable `formatted_lines`, which is a `1x1 cell array`, containing a `2x1 cell array` (in your example of two lines) which are the lines of the input text file. 

This line of code just turns the variable `formatted_lines` to the cell array of lines, instead of a cell array containing a cell array.

I made an edit to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: With pleasure. If my answer helped you, please accept it as the right answer.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: Press on the 'V' on the top left of my answer, under the reputation. You can also upvote if you found it helpful. More about accepting an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: When someone answers your question, you can upvote and accept their answer. This is done to support them, and to mark the question as solved.
Thanks